# Keras regression prediction is not same dimension as output dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, regression

Hello I'm trying to do Energy Disaggregation (predict the energy use of appliances while given the total energy consumption of a certain household.)

Now I have an input dimension of 2 because of 2 main energy measurements.
The output dimension of the Keras Sequential model should be 18 because I have 18 appliances I would like to make a prediction for.
I have enough data using the REDD dataset (this is no problem).

I have trained the model and gained reasonable loss and accuracy. 
But when I want to make a prediction for some test data, the prediction consists of values in a 1-dimensional array. Meanwhile the outputs are 18-dimensional?

How is this possible or am I trying something that isn't really viable?

Some code:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(HIDDEN_LAYER_NEURONS,input_dim=2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(18))

model.compile(loss=LOSS,
          optimizer=OPTIMIZER,
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
verbose=1, validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT)

pred = model.predict(X_test).reshape(-1)
pred.shape # prints the following 1 dimensional array: (xxxxx,) dimensional
```

The ALL_CAPS variables are constants.
X_train is 2-dim
y_train is 18-dim

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Can you be clearer about the shape of X_train, y_train, X_test and pred?

Comment: @jmsinusa My question was already correctly answered but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you are reshaping the predictions and flattening them here:

```
pred = model.predict(X_test).reshape(-1)
```

The `reshape(-1)` effectively makes the array one-dimensional. Just take the predictions directly:

```
pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a bunch. This was what I used to transpose my previous 1-dimensional array. I did not know it actually performed a transformation.

Comment: @StreamJungle Transpose is .T, not reshape to -1.